# Run linux/arm container via qemu binfmt_misc on Docker LCOW

Tags: linux, windows, docker, docker-for-windows

I release ARM binaries of my software, by running the compiler toolchain on an emulated ARM machine.

Linux can run foreign binaries by registering `qemu-user-static` in `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/`. This allows you to run an ARM32 or ARM64 Docker image on an x86_64 Docker host, as follows:

Preparation:

```sh
# Apply `binfmt_misc` changes on host OS
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static:register --reset
```

Dockerfile:

```sh
# Get x86_64 qemu-user-static binaries
FROM debian:buster
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qqy qemu-user-static

# Get cross-arch rootfs
FROM arm64v8/golang:latest
COPY --from=0 /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static
```

This works great on Docker for Linux.

It also works great on Docker for Windows when using Linux Containers (`MobyLinuxVM`)

It *doesn't* work when using Docker for Windows when using Windows Containers (LCOW / `hcsdiag` mode). I want to use this mode because it can run both Linux and Windows containers. But it's not possible to modify the `binfmt_misc` file via the `--privileged` flag:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Windows does not support privileged mode.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

Current (1803-era) versions of Hyper-V HCS run a real Linux kernel, not a WSL one. I guess it should be possible to modify the host's `binfmt_misc` directory.

- How is it possible to run a Linux/ARM container image on a Windows/x86_64 Docker host running LCOW?
- Is it possible to modify the Linux host image used by LCOW?
- Is there any other way to get a unified docker daemon that is capable of running Windows/x86_64, Linux/x86_64 and Linux/ARM Docker images?